# Can I call Word Automation Service from Provider Hosted App - SharePoint 2013 On-Premises

Tags: provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem, word-automation

I want to create Provider Hosted App for Convert Word document into PDF document. I have Created Provider Hosted App in SharePoint 2013 On-premises and it is hosted on Azure Hosting environment. Can I get SharePoint Context in my app? And Can I call Word Automation Service from my Provider Hosted App?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Word Automation Services in Provider Hosted App app Part is not possible as the Word Automation Services doesn't support CSOM or RESTful access by default .

This  can be achieved by creating a custom RESTful service  ,

Please refer this which is having a demo on the same requirement: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Convert-1e0578a1

and as far as getting the SharePoint Context in Provider Hosted App its pretty much possible with the use of the methods in SharePointContext.cs and TokenHelper.cs files.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/09/24/introducing-sharepointcontext-for-provider-hosted-sharepoint-apps/